# discordjs How to get roles by name and not by id

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I take the array of role ids in this way `message.guild.roles.cache.keyArray();` with the `keyArray` method, is there any way to get the list of id's name and not id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to get the list of id's name and not id?

I'm assuming you are trying to make a list of roles, mapped by name instead of ids.

If that's the case, it is pretty easy. `<Guild>.roles.cache` is a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection). You can use a method called [`<Collection>.map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) that maps each item to another value into an array.

---

```js
const Roles = message.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.name);

console.log(Roles);

// --> ['MyRole1', 'MyRole2', 'MyRole3', 'etc']
```